# Using C# Script in SharePoint Page

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, html

I've done quite a bit of searching (several hours actually) but I haven't been able to get this working. Basically, I have this button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Go!" id="go" onClick="getDoc()" />
```

and this block of script:

```
<script type="c#" runat="server">

public void getDoc(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    // Test to see if function was running (it's not...)
    DocFrame.Attributes["src"] = "http://www.google.com";

    // Get the current state of the dropdowns   
    String dropYear = (String)Year.SelectedValue;
    String dropDiv = (String)Division.SelectedValue;
    String dropControl = (String)Control.SelectedValue;
    String dropQuart= (String)Quarter.SelectedValue;

    // Get the Site where the list is
    using (SPSite siteCol = new SPSite("http://portal/Corporate/IT/")) {
        using (SPWeb web = siteCol.RootWeb){
            // Get the list items we need
            SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems("Year", "Division", "Control", "Quarter");
            SPListItem item = null;
            // Loop through them until we find a matching everything
            foreach (SPListItem it in items){

                if(it.Year == dropYear && it.Division == dropDiv && it.Control == dropControl && it.Quarter == dropQuart){
                    item = it;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Assign the item as a string  
            String URL = (String)item["Title"];
            // Set the iframe to the new URL
            DocFrame.Attributes["src"] = URL;
        }   
    }
}
```

It's all in the page where this is happening, please keep in mind that I've been using sharepoint for less than a week and have only ever coded in C++, so I could be doing everything horribly wrong. Anyway, it seems that getDoc() is never even getting called, so can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint doesn't allow for running C# code blocks on content pages.  Looking at what you are trying to accomplish, you can go a couple different routes:

1) Use JavaScript to do those calls with the JavaScript Object Model.  To get started with that, see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185006(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185006%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

2) Create a custom SharePoint solution in Visual Studio.  In the custom solution, add a web part (basically an ASP.NET user control) or an application page to accomplish your goal with the C# code.